# How to write clean, modular express.js applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Pretty much since forever, I've stayed away from NodeJS backend development for one reason and one reason only: Almost all Express projects I've started or I've been forced to maintain end up being a huge mess where the entire website is run on a single script that's +/- 5000 lines long.

The the following example from the ExpressJS hello world page, in this form I'd end up adding more and more routes to `app` leading to a huge mess of code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

What I can't seem to find, is how I could take a large express website, and turn it into a **modular** application where routes are **small**, **re-usable** and **easily testable**. If anyone has any idea of how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for to satisfy this question? You're asking for a large topic to be covered here, such as if I had asked "how do you model a class?". I think this question is too opinion-based to give an answer. There are hundreds of guides on how to create microservices and use that as an architectural pattern to create modular code, as well as dozens of other refactoring strategies. Maybe search through the code of larger GitHub projects, too.

Comment: Export those functions from other modules, so like `UserAuthentication.js` `export.login = function (req, res) {}` and so on so fourth, then put those in feature folders.

Comment: Create separate route handlers along with separate modules, inject the modules in `app`. Check out https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap/blob/master/minions/index.js and https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap/app.js#L91

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally use 1 file per route and put all my routing files in a `routes` folder and leverage the Router available in express.

A route file could look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then in the app file, simply add:

```
var example = require('./routes/example');
app.use('/', example);
```

The routes in the routing file are relative to the route you declare in app.use.