# Node.js: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

hi m trying to get an index page but it is showing an error: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object, structure: views>attendance>index.ejs how can I resolve this error,

controller:

```
   in controller I write this path:
   router.get('/attendance', (req, res) => res.render('attendance/index'));
```

app.js

```
  require('./models/Attendance');

  const attendanceController = require('./controllers/attendanceController');

  app.use('/attendance', attendanceController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can imagine for this not working is incorrect exports/imports.

You need to export the router like this in the controller file:

```
module.exports = router;
```

Also, by doing `router.get('/attendance'...` and applying it `app.use('/attendance',`, the application will listen for requests directed to /attendance/attendance endpoint. I'd change the controller to:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('attendance/index'));
```

See this for reference: [How to write clean, modular express.js applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739856/how-to-write-clean-modular-express-js-applications)

Comment: I have added module.exports = router;